# Acumatica ERP API

Tags: json, api, postman, schema, acumatica

I am trying to bring in an integration between our application and Acumatica ERP via REST API.
But the endpoint (https://xxxxxx.acumatica.com/entity/Default/20.200.001/StockItem/$adHocSchema) gives the whole schema but it is missing out the expandable fields like Attribute.
What we need is the whole schema with every details in it so that our initial process of Matching the fields between Acumatica and our application is done upfront.
Can anyone help on this issue.
In the below images, Change reason is the attribute field which comes under Attribute Description, but the schema endpoint doesn't give any info about change reason.

I need to have an endpoint to retrieve the complete schema including all the attributes.

Comment: [Schema](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W4odT.png)
[Attribute description](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9VAo6.png)
[In acumatica](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9HDKS.png)

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the solution myself.

```
https://xxxxxx.acumatica.com/entity/Default/20.200.001/AttributeDefinition
```

This endpoint did resolve my issue.